# Django Rest Framework: ModelSerializer as field in a ModelSerializer doesn't show choices

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, models

I have two Models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

class Order(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(article, related_name='orders')
    bought_on = models.DateTimeField()
```

and two serializer classes:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article = ArticleSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

now if I want to request the OPTIONS of orders I don't get the "choices" and it looks like this:

```
"article": {
    "type": "field", 
    "required": true, 
    "read_only": false, 
    "label": "Article"
},
```

If I delete

> article = ArticleSerializer()

from OrderSerializer everything works fine and I get a lot of information about the Articles i.e.:

```
"article": {
    "type": "field", 
    "required": true, 
    "read_only": false, 
    "label": "Article", 
    "choices": [
        {
            "display_name": "Headphones - 29.00", 
            "value": "8"
        }, 
        {
            "display_name": "Monitor- 199.00", 
            "value": "12"
        },
    ]
},
```

So here is my Question:

Is there a possibility to overwrite the choices field in the ArticleSerializer or is there another way to display the Articles in the API View as choices

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer Tom Christie has given me:

> You don't want to display it as choices if it's a nested item. Rather we should be displaying it as a nested field. (We could consider that as a valid issue, tho I'd see it as pretty low priority on my own radar, so unless someone else was running with it, then...)
>
> In terms of supporting this in your own project (rather than in core), there's some limited info on how you can go about this here... http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/ but you'd also want to dig into the existing metadata class implementation.